# Django did not display DEBUG error page despite being run on localhost and ``DEBUG=True``

Tags: python, django

In my django project I did set `DEBUG` setting to true, and I'm accessing the server from localhost.

Despite that instead of error page I get: "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was due to django raising another exception when displaying error page. There was an error in `__str__` method of one of the variables django was trying to render on the error page. It turns out that if error page throws an exceptions Django falls back to page that just says: "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.".